# Гамбургер меню не проявляется на некоторых страницах сайта

Tags: html5, media-queries, navigationbar

Создала мобильное меню габмургер. На двух старницах оно отбражается, а двух дургих отображается обычное меню. Вот код:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .hamburger {
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .line {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #bbb;
    width: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  }
  .line:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s linear;
  }
  .slide-down {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

При ширине экрана 640px на двух из четырех страниц сайта, отображается обычное меню. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: вы покажите меню в работе , ссылку на сайт к примеру

Comment: @stackanon вот скрины того как меню выглядит на мобильном устройтве с шириной 640px.
[![страница контакта][1]][1][![домашняя страница][2]][2]
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kkmdx.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0P2W1.png

Comment: Arina скриншоты мне не нужны , можете вырезать из скрина и приклеить куда угодно , а что бы понять почему не работает нужно видеть код